# retrieve all credit cards by payer_id or external_customer_id

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'd like to store user's credit cards on Paypal.

all credit cards stored with external_customer_id which is unique and the same as the id of our system.

I'd like to retrieve all credit cards with external_customer_id from Paypal.

is that possible? or I should store credit card token (or id) and find with the token?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Paypal will never, ever provide you with customer card numbers. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: to get card id or token (not number) to make payment with external_customer_id.